# how to select index of array with builder's

Tags: java, android, arrays, builder

i want select value in the array

how?

this is my code:

```
String[] str = {"1Farzad","2abbas","3ali","4hasan","5ajjad"};

for (String s:str) {
    builder.append(s);
    builder.append(" ");
}
```

for example how  select "3ali" with 2 index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this.

```
str[2]
```

Also, seems like you want this kind of loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    String s = str[i];
    builder.append(s);
    builder.append(" ");
}
```

Comment: @laalto I understood that in his loop he wants access to i and to str[i]. So I suggested this.